# Change pills colour in bootstrap 3 and can nav pills collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a website with Bootstrap 3 framework. I want to change the color of *nav-pills*, i.e. the background color as well as hover color. And I want to know that is there any way that the nav-pills collapse like navbar. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To change the nav-pills colors, just look inside bootstrap.css, you will find

```css
.nav-pills > li.active > a,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #428bca;
}
```

You can copy this into your own css and change the colors. You should also give a specific name to your class so you can easily maintain your code.